# How to take screenshot using Power button only?

Tags: buttons, screenshots

I find using <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Vol -</kbd> extremely cumbersome.

Is it possible to change this to holding <kbd>Power</kbd> Button? I'm on Android 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looking for a solution to take screenshots without pressing <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Down</kbd>, then you can [Edge Gestures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.edgegestures), to setup a gesture that will take the screenshot.

If your phone shows a menu when pressing the power button and the menu include taking a screenshot, you can set [Edge Gestures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.edgegestures) to display the menu, then you click press on `Screenshot`.

If your phone doesn't show a menu when pressing the power button, you can, as an example, set its `Swipe left and hold` from the right edge of the screen to take a screenshot as shown on the image below.

[image]

Another solution is to use [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en&gl=US) (or any other automation app such as Automate, Tasker, etc). Create a macro and set it up as shown on the image below. If you press the power button four times, it will trigger the action to take a screenshot. You have the choice to configure when pressing the power button either three, four or five times.

[image]

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the aforementioned apps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remap power button without root however, remapping any hardware button is possible without root.

There are many options available like [Button remapped](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-buttonremapper-beta-v0-2-4-new-galaxy-s-version-added.850464/) from XDA or Magisk Module or Xposed Module (named Physical Button Master Control)

For remapping any other hardware button, I will suggest you to use [Button Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton&hl=en_US)

Comment: In the Play Store description of this app it does not list Power button as "supported button". Have you actually tried this app and managed to override  Power button?

Comment: @Firelord I've edited the answer. As far as I remember, I did that back in the days (not sure though) But on testing now I find it's not possible. Maybe this was done to fix the matter that when Button mapper was closed by battery optimiser in the background all the hardware keys stopped working. And the only way was to force reboot it by long pressing the power buttons.